# Using parsley and thyme in a brine

Tags: seasoning, brining

I have a recipe for a brine that says to include a bunch of parsley when adding the ingredients to the boil. My question is, do I add the parsley whole, with the stems, or should I still separate the leaves?

It also includes thyme so the same question for that, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a brine, I would simply toss in the whole thing, stem and leaves, for parsley. In fact, parsley stems are quite flavorful. Thyme benefits from a bit of bruising to release the aroma and flavor.  So, I would roughly strip the leaves, not worrying too much if some stem was included.

Comment: I thought I had read parsley stems were bitter.

Comment: Have you tried them?

Comment: No. Because I was told they were bitter.

Comment: Try them...I use them regularly, especially in brines, pestos and salsas.

Comment: I'd use the soft stems for many herbs, like coriander and cilantro for the same reason - flavor.